# Call internal Web Api from a external server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I built a Web Api that is hosted in a server that just allow internal access and i have a Cliente-Side aplication. I have to build something in the middle to make this connection.

Cliente-Side <-> SOMETHING <-> Web Api (internal access) -> DataBase

What i need to build ? I am a begginer and i have this problem now.

Comment: You need a firewall rule, an HTTP proxy or an HTTP application that does the proxying.

Comment: @CodeCaster do you have some example of a Proxy for the Web Api ? Thanks.

Comment: No. You either need an HTTP proxy, or an HTTP application that knows your API and transports requests from the outside of your network to the inside. Really, a firewall rule is going to be much, much easier.

Comment: Is there a reason your internal access Web API can't be configured to be accessed externally? Perhaps changing the firewall or other network configurations? That's your easiest solution. Otherwise you need to build a second Web API which can be accessed externally, and has permission to call your internal Web API. The new one can accept requests from your client, forward the request to your internal Web API, and forward responses back to your client.

Comment: @DylanS for sure, thats the easiest solution. But, is not allowed. For them, this is more secure... no one can access the database from outside because this server don´t allow ! So, has to put the service or the web api in other server that allow...and they conect each other.

Comment: Standing up another Web API is your best option then. As long as you can configure it such that your new Web API is externally accessible and can reach your internal Web API, you'll be good to go. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can hit the URL of your web api from your device.  Easy route is to run the network capabilities sample here on your device and see you can hit the server using the IsReachable and IsRemoteReachable APIs.  Its Xamarin Forms, not pure Xamarin, but should let you see if you can hit your server.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2016/06/22/xam-plugins-connectivity-all-apis-sample/

Comment: I don´t know how this could help me.
Now, testing in my computer i can access the Web Api from my device and works like a charm.
But, the security department told me that i cannot use this architeture. The Web Api will be hosted in a server thats just allow internal access and i need to build another Web Api or something else, that i don´t know, to connect my Client-Side to the Web Api (back). The database is accessed just for the Web Api that allow internal access only, so the Client-side will not connect directly.
Like a PROXY

Comment: Try setting the client side proxy property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.proxy(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a function which show get and post data from the client app to web service, this will work on desktop app(win form etc). To access the web api from another web site using the same below code you have to enable cors in the web api project

```
public static  async Task UploadAsync(ReadingModel reading)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://your-api-domain.net/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/yourapi");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
        }

        // HTTP POST
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/yourapi", reading);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // do your stuff
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is yours ? I think with some changes, this is what i need.
Cors is already enabled on Web Api.
This code is like a Proxy...i have to pass some parameters on the querystring (name, mothername, fathername ...) and return a dataset... So, i build a Web Api using this part of code, thats it ?
Look my code here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466307/web-api-calling-another-web-api)

Comment: yes this is mine, I have used it in some of my project and I have show here what I have used for your help

Comment: modify and use in your project as need

Comment: Thank you very much my friend... will help me a lot! I edited with the link of my code just to check

Comment: My friend...i am trying to use this, but i have a doubt.
Because i use the code like yours on my ApiCall on Client side...i have to transport some parameters and return a DataSet...
I don´t think this will work for me.
I think i have to enter in a Controller and this, send to another controller on another WebApi... or i am wrong ?

Comment: My friend...sorry, but i am a begginer.
You used ReadingModel reading... have i to change for my parameters?
Can i use the address like this ?
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://MY_IP:1762/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Usage
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/{0}/{1}?nomePesquisa={2}&nomeMae={3}&nomePai={4}&dtNasc={5}&nrg={6}&ncpf={7}").Result;

Comment: And how i test this ? If the firts web api are calling the second one ? Because i ll have some errors and need to debug

Comment: I know it's an old question/answer but some assistance with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002283/how-to-allow-internal-mvc-web-api-from-external-site-outside-the-network would be great. Thank you.